# Excel SUM\SUMIF based on cell percentage formatting

Tags: excel, format, sum, percentage

I will copy an old post because the solution worked so well but inverse of what I need.
I have the same type of list of data, my cells are formatted as number, and percentage respectively.

> I have a row containing cells with different formatting
>
> they look the following
>
> 85 32% 45 23% 11 5% the result i need to achieve is to SUM only the
>   number formatted cells (not the percentage ones) without any
>   additional rows. No clue how to do it.

So I just need the inverse if possible so I can add all the %. 
Thanks.
Mack

Comment: What was the solution to the old post? Does your data have headers? If so you might be able to use a SUMIF function based on those

Answer (score 1):

Lets say values are in A1:A4, copy this formula to B1:B4

```
=CELL("format";A1) & T(NOW())
```

Then write this formula to sum all values with %

```
=SUMIF(B1:B4;"P*";A1:A4)
```

The formula in B1:B4 is volatile but you still need to press F9, to  recalculate the sumif, if you only change a format in A1:A4 without changing any value

Comment: this seems to get the math I needed! One huge step forward, now could I get the two to fit into one cell and sum at the bottom of the column? Would that cause to many circular ref or whatever? Or rather can I use the later formula only, I guess if there is a way to extract the format in a code like p0 why not have it do that and then add them up all in the same cell? Or is that asking too much?

Comment: I tried to use an array formula in order to use just one formula, without the aux column. The cell function dont seems to accept a range as second argument. I didn't give up just yet :) Maybe other members out there can give it a try. Several heads think better...

Comment: What is the reason for the "& T(NOW())" bit at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is A1:A6 then the following should do the trick:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A6,"<1",A1:A6)
```

Comment: This assumes that the percentages won't be 100% or higher...and that the numbers won't be <1

Comment: It does come with assumptions, correct. Not over 100% and no non-percent numbers below 1. If the data does not adhere to this then another solution would be more applicable.